# DBMS_DATA_MINING.CREATE_MODEL causes "ORA-40103: invalid case-id column: TID" on 11.2.0.1.0 64b, but on 10g OK

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-mining, oracle11gr2

I have a problem with DBMS_DATA_MINING.CREATE_MODEL on version 11.2. On 10g this code below works OK, and I'm quite sure that on 11.1 it works too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "SH"."ITEMS" AS SELECT PROD_ID AS item FROM SALES GROUP BY PROD_ID;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "SH"."TRANSACTIONS" AS SELECT "SH"."SALES"."PROD_ID" AS item , "SH"."SALES"."CUST_ID" tid FROM "SH"."SALES" where cust_id between 100001 AND 104500 GROUP BY cust_id, prod_id;
CREATE TABLE "SH"."AR_SETTINGS" ( "SETTING_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), "SETTING_VALUE" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) );
INSERT INTO SH.AR_SETTINGS (SETTING_NAME, SETTING_VALUE) VALUES ('ASSO_MAX_RULE_LENGTH', '6' );
INSERT INTO SH.AR_SETTINGS (SETTING_NAME, SETTING_VALUE) VALUES( 'ASSO_MIN_CONFIDENCE', TO_CHAR(0.7));
INSERT INTO SH.AR_SETTINGS (SETTING_NAME, SETTING_VALUE) VALUES( 'ASSO_MIN_SUPPORT', TO_CHAR(0.1));

BEGIN DBMS_DATA_MINING.CREATE_MODEL( model_name => 'AR_sh', mining_function => DBMS_DATA_MINING.ASSOCIATION, data_schema_name => 'sh', data_table_name => 'transactions', case_id_column_name => 'tid', settings_schema_name => 'sh', settings_table_name => 'ar_settings'); END;
```

causes:

```
ORA-40103: invalid case-id column: TID
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATA_MINING", line 1779
ORA-06512: at line 1
40103. 00000 - "invalid case-id column: %s"
*Cause: The column designated as case-id is not of one of CHAR, VARCHAR2,
NUMBER data type. Case-id columns of type CHAR and VARCHAR2 must
be of length less than or equal to 128 bytes.
*Action: Change the schema of your input data to supply a case-id column
of appropriate data type and/or length.
```

to be sure:

```
describe "SH"."TRANSACTIONS"
Name Null Type 
--
ITEM NOT NULL NUMBER 
TID NOT NULL NUMBER
```

and

```
select * from v$version;
```

returns:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production 
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production 
CORE    11.2.0.1.0  Production 
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

[The sample code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/odm/odm-samples-194497.html) from `dmardemo.sql` causes the same error.
I don't know what is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. After couple of system restarts it started to work. Without any reason (no configuration changes).

Answer (score 4):

Your code and the samples both work for me.  I'm also using 11.2.0.1.0, except I'm using 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

I'm not sure what this means.  Maybe there was a problem with your installation?  You might want to look at [Verifying Your Data Mining Installation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/datamine.112/e16807/appendix_a.htm#CDEJJIDJ).

Comment: I doubt Vista/7 that makes a difference.  Once thing Oracle seems to do very well is keep their software consistent between operating systems.  I'm surprised that a difference in `cust_id` would make a difference either; your example still worked for me even when I changed the range to return no results.  Can you reproduce your problem on another database, one from a fresh 11g install?  If your database was upgraded from 10g it looks like there are some additional steps that you must take for data mining: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/datamine.112/e16807/upgrade_odm.htm#sthref285

Comment: it happens on fresh 11.2 installation (without upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

or maybe the range `where cust_id between 100001 AND 104500` changed between versions?

Answer (score 2):

Purely a guess, but is it possible that a synonym for TRANSACTIONS is not pointing to SH.TRANSACTIONS but some other table?  I know you specify the schema name SH, but may still cause issues if this is the case (describe TRANSACTIONS to see).

Comment: i checked using describe and it was OK